# How do I retrieve all records between a date range and then filtered by time of day?

Tags: mysql

My dateTime column has entries like this going back months:
2019-03-11 07:00:00.000

I would like to retrieve all the data from mondays, but then further filtered by the time of day.

This is what I have so far but I dont know how to refine it any further.

```
WITH 
  cteMonday (dates1, Average) AS
  (
select [Date], [High] - [Low] AS 'average'
--select *
 from [Trading].[dbo].[DAX30m]
where DATEPART(dw, Date) = 2
AND [DATE] BETWEEN '2019-03-11' AND '2019-03-24'
  )

  select * from ctemonday
```

Comment: Looks more like sqlserver than mysql - is this tagged correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the DATEPART function to extend your filter criteria, e.g.:

> ... AND DATEPART(hh, Date) > lowerLimit AND DATEPART(hh, Date) <
>   upperLimit

Comment: Works beautifully.  DATEPART(hh,[Date]) >= 14 AND DATEPART(hh,[Date]) <= 15 - I tried to upvote your answer but I have zero reputation. sorry :)